# PDF lecture notes of various courses by Leonard Susskind

Tags: education, specific-reference

Leonard Susskind had recorded many video lectures across many branches of physics and all of can be found on [this](http://theoreticalminimum.com/courses) official website. Pdf versions of three of the video courses (taken and shared by some generous person) are available in the following links to download for free

1. [Statistical Mechanics and Thermodynamics,](https://www.lapasserelle.com/statistical_mechanics/)
2. [General Relativity,](https://www.lapasserelle.com/general_relativity/)
3. [Cosmology](https://www.lapasserelle.com/cosmology/).

There also exist three textbooks by Susskind based on these videos lectures (and I own all of them)

4. [Classical mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0141976225),
5. [Quantum Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FD36G1Q),
6. [Special Relativity and Classical theory of fields.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MR1ZPOS)

More can be found [here](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~moreyjc/pdfs/) and [here](http://www.welkinsky.com/Welkin_Sky/Susskind_Lectures_List.html). Hope I didn't miss any. But he has given many other [supplemental courses](http://theoreticalminimum.com/courses/supplemental) as well such as Quantum Entanglement, Particle Physics 1: Basic Concepts, Particle Physics 2: Standard Model, Particle Physics 3: Supersymmetry and Grand Unification, String Theory, Cosmology and Black Holes etc. But unfortunately, I could not find the PDF notes of any of these supplemental courses on the Internet. Does anyone have the PDF notes of these lectures? Please share the link if available. Thanks!

Comment: The links in Cosmology are broken. If you have the pdf files, please upload them.

Answer (score 2):

On this side https://advancedmath.org/
there are private pdfs for
Statistical Mechanics and Thermodynamics
Advanced Quantum Mechanics
Special Relativity
Cosmology